# Merging hashes, summing values that have the same key

Tags: ruby, hash-map

I'm trying to group by keys in an Array of Hashes in the following form and add their totals. Maybe with #map and #reduce/#inject. I know there is a more compact way to do this.

Given I have

```
codes_and_totals = [{'1001' => 153, '212' => 153}, {'212' => 1}]
```

When I run

`process_codes_and_totals(codes_and_totals)`

Then the return value should be

`=> {'1001' => 153, '212' => 154}`

Currently `#process_codes_and_totals` looks like this

```
def process_codes_and_totals(codes_and_totals)
    totals_across_locations = {}
    codes_and_totals.each do |location|
      location.each do |class_code, total|
        totals_across_locations[class_code] ||= 0
        totals_across_locations[class_code] += total
      end
    end

    totals_across_locations
end
```

Comment: Please try to edit your title to reflect what your code is doing. Saying you want better code in Code Review is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Marc-Andre, let me know if there is anything else I can do to make this clearer/better.

Comment: "Better", "more compact", "faster", etc. are all implied for questions on Code Review. The site standard is to simply state exactly what the code accomplishes. See [ask].

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 to 3. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: As a note, some people recommend using #each_with_object and a blank hash as the argument. More info is here http://technology.customink.com/blog/2014/10/14/better-hash-injection-using-each-with-object/.

Comment: Related SO question: [Sum 2 hashes attributes with the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4091487/322020)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way might be to use `#reduce` (as you suggest) and `Hash#merge` with a block:

```
totals = codes_and_totals.reduce({}) do |sums, location|
  sums.merge(location) { |_, a, b| a + b }
end
```

The merge-block is only invoked if a key exists in both the hashes being merged, so we don't need to guard against `nil` or start with a zero value. If the block runs, it's because there are two number values that need to be merged (i.e. added, in this case).

Comment: What is the `_` for as the first block argument to the merge?

Comment: `_` is the conventional name for a "throw-away" variable whose value you don't care about.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for nested hashes?